# How to draw a signal that is piecewise constant and piecewise wave function

Tags: matlab, signals, matlab-figure

I am a very new in Matlab. How can I draw a signal containing a constant, a wave function, and another constant, as in the image below?

[image: signal]

Comment: Easy `imshow(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5anQH.png','png'))` . Joking aside, you need to give more information about what you want to do, what you have tried, and what have failed. Your question is too broad as it is right now

Answer (score 0):

```
figure % create a figure
hold on % Keep plot when making more plots

% first section
plot([0,9],[2500 2500],'k') % plot a constant line from 0-9 where y = 2500

% second section
x = linspace(0,9); % create array from 0 to 9 in 100 points
f = @(x) 2500 + sin(x*pi/9)*2500; % create wave function, using x
plot(x+9,f(x),'k')

% third section
plot([18,24],[2500 2500],'k') % plot a constant line from 18-24, y = 2500

% Change y limits
ylim([0 5000])
```